# How to find a group $G$ and a homomorphism $f$ , given $f(G)$ and $\ker f$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Find a group $G$ and a homomorphism $f$ from $G$, so that $f(G)=S_3$ and $\ker(f)=A_4$. Is $G$ abelian?

I know the meaning of group homomorphism and a kernel , but have encountered such a problem for the first time so need guidance in solving it. I think the order of the required group will be $72 = o(S_3)\times o(A_4)$.

Comment: Can't you just set $G = S_3\oplus A_4$, and define $f:G\to S_3$ as the $f((a,b)) = a$ (just one of the projections you get because $\times$ is a categorical product).

Comment: @Mark : You seem to confused about the difference between a Comment and an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you write $A_4$ in a way that it is evident that you can make $S_3$ act faithfully on it?  Perhaps write $A_4$ is products of transpositions, then find three transpositions that you can move around via $S_3$.

If $G$ were abelian, the cosets of $A_4$ would form an abelian group.  You are told which group these cosets form.  Is it abelian?

(In some detail, you are solving an [extension problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_problem).  You are given a normal subgroup of $G$, $A_4$, and the quotient $G/A_4 \cong S_3$.  You are asked to extend $A_4$ by $S_3$.  The [semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) is an example of this, where the quotient acts on the normal subgroup by automorphisms.)

Comment: Would G=S3⊕A4, and $:G→S3 : $((a,b))=a suffice as an answer?

Comment: @AMT : For the "Find" part of the problem, yes.  For the question at its end, there is more to say.

Comment: Since A4 & S3 are not abelian ,so their direct sum should not be abelian?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$0\to A_4\to G\stackrel{f}{\to} S_3\to 0$$
is [exact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence). You are correct about the order.